# Is there a cross platform AutoCloseable Iterable solution for Scala?

Tags: scala, scala.js, scala-3

I [am porting](https://github.com/bblfish/banana-play) a library banana-rdf to Scala3. The library aims to provide a no-cost efficient interface for RDF libraries written in Scala, JS (and hopefully even native at some point).

I am currently working on the implementation for the [Jena](https://jena.apache.org) library that returns AutoCloseable iterators, which made me wonder how I should best deal with those.

- If I convert that type to an scala `Iterable` then I loose the closeable interface on it, losing the information that the caller should make sure to close it before using it;
- I looked at `scala.util.Using`, but that requires the resource to be iterated through, which is something for the calling code to determine, not the library;
- should one just return the Java iterator? But I would need to check if that plays well with ScalaJS code
- Other ideas?

Comment: Scala has its own `Iterator`s and converting to and from a Java one should be fairly cheap. Can you just make a wrapper that `extends Iterator[Something] with AutoClosable`? Contrary to Java, `AutoCloseable` has no syntactical benefit, so maybe `Closeable` could be enough.

Answer (score 0):

One could use the Java Iterable and Closeable interfaces, and build on that.